# How do I reference a directory in Python so it works on multiple computers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, scripting, pyautogui

I created a Python script that I want to use on different computers. I'm using os and pyautogui modules since for pyautogui I have multiple screenshots stored in the folder where py python script is located, also I have a .txt file from which I grab information relevant to the script and should be different on each of those computers. 
This is the reference in the script:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Script')
p.FAILSAFE = False

# extracts login and password from a txt file, for each user
credentials = open("login.txt", "r")
for line in credentials:
    pieces = line.split(":")
    email = pieces[0]
    password = pieces[1]
```

How do I make it accustom to any computer where the script is located and will it work with pyinstaller after I converted the .py file into .exe. Thanks!

Comment: Don't mind the p.FAILSAFE = False it's for pyautogui

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory and point to it, the code will be:

```
directory_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],'Desktop','Script')
if not os.path.isdir(directory_path): os.mkdir(directory_path)
```

`os.environ['USERPROFILE']` gets the user directory for each user in each machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to reference user home directory. This will work in Unix and Windows.